# Having trouble adding characters to a linked list structure?

Tags: pointers, linked-list, structure

I am currently unsuccessful at being prompt to add a char for my current program. I am able to add a digit but it will post the prompt to add a character but skips to input portion and directly asks me if I want to continue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    struct node
    {
        int num;
        char gender[3];
        struct node *ptr;
    };

    typedef struct node NODE;
    NODE *head, *first, *temp = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int choice = 1;
    first = 0;

    while (choice)
    {
        head  = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        printf("Enter the Student Identification Number\n");

        scanf("%d", &head-> num);
        printf("Enter the Student gender (M)or(F)\n");
        scanf("%c", &head-> gender);
        if (first != 0)
        {
            temp->ptr = head;
            temp = head;
        }else
        {
            first = temp = head;
        }
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Would you like to do another entry(Type No(0) or Yes(1))?\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    temp->ptr = 0;
    /*  reset temp to the beginning */
    temp = first;
    printf("\nStudent Information\n");
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        printf("Student ID number: %d\n", temp->num);
        printf("Student gender: %c\n", temp->gender);
        count++;
        temp = temp -> ptr;
    }
    printf("No. of Students inputted into system: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend that you invest more effort explaining a) what you have to accomplish, b) what behavior you expected, c) what behavior you observe instead.

Comment: a) I need to create a program using linked lists to input student ID and gender and in turn print the id and gender b)I expected to be able to enter a character after the enter gender prompt c) What I ultimately got when I ran the program what the "Enter the Student gender (M)or(F)\n" immediately followed by "Would you like to do another entry(Type No(0) or Yes(1))?" and it did not let me input anything for the previous question